# Issue with floated elements on desktop view

Tags: css

I am working on a layout that contain some mainbars and some sidebars,  on mobile it is fine but there is issue on desktop view.

There are unnecessary spaces between the mainbars and between the sidebars on desktop view.

Please let me know the proper way to arrange the elements using css.

See the attached images[image][image][image]

```css
        .content {
            background-color: brown;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            color: white;
            font-size: 2em;
            max-width: 800px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .main {
            background-color: green;
            width: 70%;
            float: left;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 2px solid white;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
            clear: both;
        }
        .sidebar {
            background-color: blue;
            width: 30%;
            float: right;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            border: 2px solid white;
            margin-bottom: 8px;
            clear: both;
        }
        .clear{
            clear: both;
        }
        @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
            .main, .sidebar {
                width: 100%;
                clear: both;
            }
        }
```

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" />
</head>
<div class="content">
    <div class="sidebar">
        1-Sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        2-Sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        3-Main
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        4-Sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        5-Main
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        6-Main
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        7-Sidebar
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Update for @A Haworth reply:
Please see the attached image.
[image]

Comment: Don't use floating elements. In the 2023 there are Flexbox or Grid properties!!

Comment: @Sfili_81 Can you make it for me using Flexbox?

Comment: Sorry but i don't want to code for you. Try and if you get stuck ask here

Answer (score 2):

CSS float is useful when you want e.g. text to float around an element but it leads to problems in the given situation.

CSS grid can help instead for the wider viewport  settings.

UPDATE: the picture showing the required layout has changed and the original answer here no longer applies. So here's a slightly different scheme.

What you can do is alter your HTML so all the main elements come within one parent div and all the sidebar elements under another.

Then we use grid on the wider viewport to position the two (main and sidebar) at 70% and 30% of the width respectively and the new setup means the two columns are independent of each other - it's just the two divs having their children one after the other vertically.

For the narrower viewport we make the content element be a single column grid. We force each element to go into the grid row we want.There appears not to be an obvious algorithm for deciding this so each of the elements sets a CSS variable (which you will have to set when you know exactly which element is to go where on the narrower setting) which is then used to inform the grid which position it should be in.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" />
  <style>
    .content {
      background-color: brown;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      color: white;
      font-size: 2em;
      width: min(800px, 100vw);
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 7fr 3fr;
    }
    
    .main>* {
      background-color: green;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 2px solid white;
      margin-bottom: 8px;
    }
    
    .sidebar>* {
      background-color: blue;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      border: 2px solid white;
      margin-bottom: 8px;
    }
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
      .sidebar>*,
      .main>* {
        grid-row: var(--r);
      }
      .content {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      }
      .main,
      .sidebar {
        display: contents;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="main">
      <div style="--r: 3;">
        3-Mains<br>more lines<br>lines..
      </div>
      <div style="--r: 5;">
        5-Main
      </div>
      <div style="--r: 6;">
        6-Main<br>more lines<br>lines...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div style="--r: 1;">
        1-Sidebar
      </div>
      <div style="--r: 2;">
        2-Sidebar
      </div>
      <div style="--r: 4;">
        4-Sidebar
      </div>
      <div style="--r: 7;">
        7-Sidebar
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

The layout for narrower viewports does not on the face of it have a definite logic so it seems best to leave the HTML as it is as then the narrow viewport layout is just the natural layout.

For the wider viewports, the trick here is to define a grid with 70%/30% width split and also to set the flow to be dense. This means the system will fill up from the top each time if there is space. So for example in this case the main which is number 3 will go into column 1 row 1 as there is space for it (I've added a bit of extra text to prove that the system adjusts to the content).

```css
.content {
  background-color: brown;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  width: min(800px, 100vw);
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 7fr 3fr;
  grid-auto-flow: dense;
  row-gap: 8px;
}

.main {
  background-color: green;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid white;
  ;
  grid-column: 1;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 2px solid white;
  grid-column: 2;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .main,
  .sidebar {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .content {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" />
</head>
<div class="content">
  <div class="sidebar">
    1-Sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    2-Sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    3-Main
    <p>with some more text over more than one line</p>
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    4-Sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    5-Main
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    6-Main
  </div>
  <div class="sidebar">
    7-Sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Note: I have inferred that as you set a max width to .content you want the whole viewport width to be used if it is narrower than 800px. Obviously change the width setting if something else is required.

Comment: @A Haworth, Thank you for your time, I don't want blank spaces at the bottom of each sidebars and mainbars, all the sidebars must be stacked together similarly all the mainbars must be stacked together.

Comment: But the image you gave of the expected result had a gap, and your code has an 8px margin. Could you describe exactly what you want? Meanwhile, remove the gap property in the grid and see if that is what  you want. If so maybe you could update your question to show the correct layout? Thanks.

Comment: Actually, maybe I have totally misunderstood what you want. Are you saying all those in column 1 should be stacked together (albeit with an 8px gap between them) and all those in column 2 should be stacked together (with a similar gap between them) but the two columns should have nothing to do with each other position-wise?

Comment: @A Haworth, I am not talking about the gaps, it's alright. what I want is in the image in my updated question.

Comment: I've updated the answer to accommodate the updated layout.

Comment: @A Haworth, desktop view is fine now but sequence of elements in mobile view is not ok.

Comment: Whoops! There was a missing display: contents for the narrow viewports in .main and .sidebar. This tells the system to use the children of those elements as if they were children of the elements' parents - so the grid settings take effect. Please try now and let me know if OK.

Comment: Thank you @A Haworth, your solution worked, but unfortunately it is not applicable in my scenario as the count of mainbars and sidebars are variable, and support for display:contents is limited.

Comment: How will you tell the system what the layout for the narrow viewports is to be? That is the main problem here because it doesn't seem to be algorithmic. Also I was surprised you can't use display: contents because most modern browsers have been supporting it for some time. What restrictions are there on the CSS? (Something else to put in your question!).

Comment: I think you have well understood the issue.Is there any solution exists keeping the sidebars and mainbars direct children of the content div?

Comment: It will be a horrible fiddle and probably requiring JS - a pity you can't use display: contents as it solves the problem! Also I should have raised the question of accessibility. If a screen reader user 'hears' the structure you have now it will be pretty confusing.